# Using a database in mysql - wamp server

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to test mysql on my machine. I made sure the directory is set to the one where all my databases are, however when I try to use one it doesn't work.
For example if I write in the command prompt:

```
mysql> use world;
```

I get this error : `ERROR 1049 <42000>: Unknown database 'world'`

Comment: use SHOW DATABASES; and find is world database exists or not

Comment: @TamilSelvan it shows folders in the same directory as world, but it doesn't show world.sql. When I add a folder, it sees it as a database. but it's not seeing the files with .sql extension. why?

Comment: creating the DB is not just creating a folder and a file in it. you should use the SQL commands for that. See my answer

Comment: Folders? world.sql? You have very strange assumptions about how MySQL works. I suggest you read the manual or find a tutorial—there's no way to learn MySQL by pure guessing.

Comment: mysql > create database world

Answer (score 0):

first you will need to create a database. Should you have something like phpmyadmin then you can use that to have a simple GUI for creating the DB, otherwise, use CREATE DATABASE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

Answer (score 0):

create the database world using the Wamp server..
Then run this Query.